# google map not rendering under .collapse bootstrap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have looked every where and am starting to go crazy. I know I am close, but can't get it.

I have my html:

```
<div id="glasgow-map" class="collapse">
    <div class="map">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:350px;"></div>
    </div>
    </div><!--end collapse-->
```

my JS is:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.860949,-4.244938);
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Taylor Hopkinson Associates'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


$('#glasgow-map').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center);
})
```

From all the other info I have seen I know I need the (map, "resize) but I am getting this error in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined

Any help would be fantastic. It's been a long day!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Help @kamlesh, I think you are right, but this is the way I finally managed to get it to work, and also for multiple maps - if anyone needs help with that, it's below.

I stripped the google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); and added the initialize to the .collapse button for when it is clicked. This way there is no need for the resize.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.860949,-4.244938);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.510142,-0.143314);
  var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4004236,0.0172711);

  var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 16,
 center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var mapOptions2 = {
 zoom: 16,
 center: myLatlng2,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var mapOptions3 = {
 zoom: 16,
  center: myLatlng3,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas1'), mapOptions);
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'), mapOptions2);
var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas3'), mapOptions3);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Taylor Hopkinson Associates'
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map2,
    title: 'Taylor Hopkinson Associates'
});
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng3,
    map: map3,
    title: 'Taylor Hopkinson Associates'
});

}




$('#glasgow-map').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    initialize();

    })

$('#london-map').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
initialize();

    })

$('#bromley-map').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    initialize();

    })
```

Perhaps there is a way of streamlining this code, but it certainly works for me.